# Managing shared styles and assets in Ngrx-nx Monorepo

Tags: angular, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I am trying to set up shared styles and assets (i.e. fonts) in a nrwl-nx monorepo for use in libraries and apps.

My desired outcome is having a library 'theme' that provides

1. shared styles
2. scss variables and mixins
3. fonts

for other libs and apps.

For 1. and 2. I found a great answer here: [How to manage SCSS stylesheets across a monorepo with different libraries sharing variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428245/how-to-manage-scss-stylesheets-across-a-monorepo-with-different-libraries-sharin#answer-56970945)

Tim Consolazio presents a nice (and Nrwl-inspired) approach of handling shared styles across a monorepo. The basic idea is having an entry point scss in `libs/theme/scss/src/lib/theme.scss` that is being imported in `apps/myapp/src/styles.scss`. This is working fine.

What I am having a hard time though is getting this to work with providing fonts to be used in the shared styles, i.e. I have a `libs/theme/scss/src/lib/fonts.scss` that imports fonts from the assets folder within the themes lib.

The project structure is

```
- apps
  - myapp
    - src
      - styles.scss (@import 'theme' from the lib)
- libs
  - theme
    - assets
      - src
        - lib
          - fonts
            - myfont.ttf
            ...
    - scss
      - src
        - lib
          - fonts.scss
          - theme.scss
          - variables.scss
          ...
```

The goal is to have the assets within the `themes` library. I tried adding to the `architect.build.assets` array in `angular.json`. But I can't figure out the correct path to set when referencing the fonts in the fonts stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'My-Font';
  src: url('./assets/fonts/myfont.eot');
  src: url('./assets/fonts/myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('./assets/fonts/myfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./assets/fonts/myfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./assets/fonts/myfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So after a lot of headaches I came to a rather simple solution as suggested in this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@nit3watch/angular-shared-assets-with-multiple-apps-nrwl-nx-b4801c05c771) with slight tweaks to get it working.

The project structure:

```
- libs
  - theme
    - assets
        - fonts
            - myfont.ttf
            ...
```

The key is to add the glob for the shared assets to **each app** in your `angular.json`, e.g. in

- `projects.my-project-1.architect.build.options.assets`
- `projects.my-project-2.architect.build.options.assets`
- ...

```
{
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "libs/theme/assets/",
    "output": "/assets/"
}
```

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md#project-assets

Also, I had to change the import paths of the font files in scss to absolute paths:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'My-Font';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/myfont.eot');
  src: url('/assets/fonts/myfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/assets/fonts/myfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/assets/fonts/myfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/assets/fonts/myfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Works for me, but I'd be happy to learn about more elegant solutions - especially the need to copy-paste the assets glob for every new app bothers me.

Comment: Have you found a better solution, that you dont need to copy your assets to a new app?